# Product prices array is not giving expected result while sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Product prices array is not giving me an expected result.

```
let productPrices = [10.33, 2.55, 1.06, 5.77];
console.log(productPrices.sort());
```

Result of above code:

```
(4) [1.06, 10.33, 2.55, 5.77]
```

Expecting:

```
(4) [1.06, 2.55, 5.77, 10.33]
```

Comment: sort() method for arrays in JS is not meant for numbers directly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to make a function for comparing.

```js
let productPrices = [10.33, 2.55, 1.06, 5.77];
console.log(productPrices.sort((a,b)=>a-b));
```

Comment: it's working fine, with your solution.

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates